# How to find ActiveRecords which have attribute either equal to value or be null in Yii2

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, yii2

I basically have an active query and I either want to filter that column if it matched the ID or is null

```
MyTable::find()->andFilterWhere(['in', 'org_id', [null, $org_id]])->all();
```

currently using this, works fine for the `$org_id`, but it will not return `null` values.
I tried this to see if I could get any null results, but no avail

```
MyTable::find()->andFilterWhere(['in', 'org_id', null])->all();
```

Any tips?

Comment: Using IN and NULL is simply not possible

Comment: It's possible with `or` operator.

Comment: With `and` it's also possible but will always give empty result.

Comment: Of course, I was talking about IN

Answer (score 5):

Correct you query like that:

```
MyTable::find()
   ->andFilterWhere(['in', 'org_id', $this->org_id])
   ->orWhere(['org_id' => null])
   ->all();
```

You can specify `IS NULL` condition with array also, `orWhere` is enough because this condition does not depend on attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a filter of multiple values, the following query will result in cell with null or values in an array:

```
$query->andWhere(['or', ['in', 'column', $value_array], ['column' => null]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To reinforce arogachev's answer, this is a good reference, if you wanted to just query for null results:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6788

```
$query->andfilterWhere('org_id' => null)
```

This query doesn't work because filterWhere removes empty params.

For null results, use:

```
$query->andWhere('org_id' => null)
```

Answer (score 0):

To completely answer this question, let's reiterate what we really want.

We need to get all records from some table which have some specific `'field'` to be equal either to given `$value` or to `null`.

Given that definition, we can translate it directly into `Query` call:

```
$query->andWhere(['or', ['field' => $value], ['field' => null]]);
```

---

This is somewhat suboptimal in cases when `$value` is `null`, because it gives the SQL `WHERE (field IS NULL) OR (field IS NULL)`. 
You can mitigate it by wrapping the `andWhere` call with `if` statement:

```
if ($value === null)
    $query->andWhere(['field' => null]);
else
    $query->andWhere(['or', ['field' => $value], ['field' => null]]);
```

or depending on your tastes, using ternary operator:

```
$query->andWhere(
    $value === null
        ? ['field' => null]
        : ['or', ['field' => $value], ['field' => null]]
);
```

In any case, using `andFilterWhere` completely defeats the purpose of your query, because it exists solely to remove pieces like `['field' => null]` from the queries.